# how can i use this modal within my foreach loop? (HTML / Razor)

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I have a button that when clicked should open a modal with a confirmation stating whether the user would like to delete the selected line or not, hence on the modal, there is a 'Yes' and 'No' option. With the 'Yes' button carrying out the onclick function which is responsible for deleting the line item (These operations take place within my controller and are not part of this question). To provide a bit of background, originally the onclick function had been part of my button, which now opens the modal, and this worked perfectly as intended. However, now that button serves only one purpose, and that is to open the modal. Within the modal, the onclick function has now been moved to the 'Yes' button. But now, this onclick function does not work as it use to, and i believe this is something to do with the foreach loop that all of this is in.

Below is the code for the button and modal:

```
@Model.CategoryList.result
        @if (Model.CategoryList.result == "")
        {
            int count = 0;

            foreach (String dataLine in Model.CategoryList.userData)
            {

                string countString = count.ToString();
                string target = "dataLine" + countString;
                string trigger = "#" + target;
                string deleteHolder = dataLine.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[0];

                <p>
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="@trigger" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                        @dataLine.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[0]
                    </a>

                    <button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteHolder" id="@dataLine.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[1]"></button>

                </p>

               <div class="modal" id="deleteHolder" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("DeleteCategoryLine", "Index", new { id = dataLine.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[1] })'">Yes</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                count++;


            }
        }
```

The problem i have is: The onclick event deletes a line in the text file, that is why i have count, trigger and target to identify WHICH line to delete. However, after moving the onclick event to my modal, it will always delete the first line in the text file. I am unsure as to why this happens? Do i not understand the implications a modal presents?

My controller Action:

```
public ActionResult DeleteCategoryLine(int id, string changedItem)
        {
            string strFilePath = "~/App_Data/Category.txt";
            string strSearchText = id.ToString();
            string strOldText;

            string n = changedItem;
            StreamReader sr = System.IO.File.OpenText(Server.MapPath(strFilePath));
            while ((strOldText = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] x = strOldText.Split(',');

                if (!x[1].Contains(strSearchText))
                {
                    n += strOldText + Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
            sr.Close();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath(strFilePath), n);
}
```

Comment: Something to note here is. In HTML, id's should ALWAYS be unique. but you have thew id `deleteHolder` and foreach value in `userData`, a new element will be created with this  id. I would suggest trying to prefixing this with a unique value in each of the items in `userData`. Maybe an ID.

Comment: Also, where is the function?

Comment: The onclick function is this ``onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("DeleteCategoryLine", "Index", new { id = dataLine.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[1] })'"`` sorry i feel i miss worded this, its not necessarily a function.

Comment: For some reason, when the 'Yes' button on the modal is clicked, it will execute the onclick event as shown above, however as mentioned in the question. It only deletes the first line in the text file, where as if the exact same onclick event happened on the original button (the one that is now responsible for opening the modal) it would have worked as intended, and deleted the correct line.

Comment: Where is your controller action? What is it showing? What are you expecting?

Comment: The controller action lies within the Index controller under the name DeleteCategoryLine, check the updated question with this ActionResult included.

Comment: Apologies, i had uploaded the wrong ActionResult at first, the correct one should be up now

Comment: What is the value of `changedItem`? It looks like you don't pass it at all?

Comment: I don't believe changedItem does anything at the moment, it simply passes as null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213070/discussion-between-jamess-and-seventhwarhawk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our chat, the answer to this issue was that the ID of the modal was not unique and so it was creating the first and that's that.

I advised OP to suffix the modal with a unique ID

```
deleteHolder_@dataLine.Split(Model.CategoryList.delimiterChar)[1]
```

and it seems to have worked.